# Proof of Stake Contracts, after deployment?

Tags: contract-deployment

I'm curious, for reference lets use this tokens for example. They all seem to have close to the same contract.
1. PoSToken (POS) - https://etherscan.io/address/0xee609fe292128cad03b786dbb9bc2634ccdbe7fc#code
2. Rebellious (REBL) - https://etherscan.io/address/0x5f53f7a8075614b699baad0bc2c899f4bad8fbbf#code
3. Staker (STR) - https://etherscan.io/address/0xbae235823d7255d9d48635ced4735227244cd583#code

Looking at the "Write Contract" page of these tokens on etherscan and this spot "4. ownerSetStakeStartTime".

I'm curious to know after the contract creator deploys this sort of contract do they have to place a number of some sort or timestamp in this spot "4. ownerSetStakeStartTime" then write to start the contract.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be the only place where the value of `stakeStartTime` can be set, so yes, the owner has to set that variable. I only looked at the first one, but I assume the rest of them work the same way.

I didn't try to interpret what the contract actually does with the information but if the contract is meant to be used in any meaningful way, then the variable probably needs to be set to a non-zero value. (It's zero if it's not set.)